# Why does my second explicit wait not work if an action was performed on the previous one?

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to switch up to two toggles on a website that expand or hide parts of a CMS tree ([expanded picture for context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLMqp.jpg)) that does not have an API. They are on the same hierarchy level of the tree. The toggles are randomly set on the "hidden" or "expanded" view and I need the first one to be set to hidden and the second to be expanded.

Generally, my code works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
   iframe_cms_subpages = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/iframe'))) # (unfortunately, I have to go with an abs xpath here)
   print("iframe found!")
except TimeoutException:
   print("Loading iframe took too long")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_cms_subpages)

try:
   main_menu1 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='npsLogic_nodeViewEntry_c_/main_menu1_npsLogic']/img[@alt='-']")))
   print("main_menu1 open! Close it first")
   main_menu1.click()
   print("closed!")
except TimeoutException:
   print("main_menu1 was either already closed or something went wrong.")

try:
   main_menu2 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='npsLogic_nodeViewEntry_e_/main_menu2_npsLogic']/img[@alt='+']")))
   print("main_menu2 closed! Needs to be opened first")
   main_menu2.click()
   print("main_menu2 opened!")
except TimeoutException:
   print("main_menu2 was either already open or something went wrong."
```

The "+" in the xpath is present if it is closed (hidden), for the "-" it is vice versa (expanded).

**My issue**: I have tested this in all four scenarios and the code only works if up to one of the two toggles has to be switched to have both be set correctly, i.e. if either both of them are open, both of them are closed or the first one is closed and second one open (correct settings right away). If both of them need to be switched, i.e. if the first one is open and the second one is closed, the second try statement throws a `TimeOutException`. Why does the second explicit wait not work if an action was performed based on the previous one?

**Notes**: I included the iframe because I thought it might be relevant; that explicit wait works. I noticed that there is a "c" in the first xpath and an "e" in the second, but that is part of the path for some reason, not a typo.

Do I perhaps have an incorrect understanding of how explicit waits work?

Comment: You probably want to wait for each element to be clickable, not just present.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it didn't fix the issue, but it is definitely the right way to go about this. Included it in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time one of the elements is clicked, the elements were not recognized by the webdriver anymore. This can be fixed by just switching back to parent frame and then back into the iframe again! I have also changed the explicit wait type to element_to_be_clickable in line with the recommendation of Greg:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
   iframe_cms_subpages = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/iframe'))) # (unfortunately, I have to go with an abs xpath here)
   print("iframe found!")
except TimeoutException:
   print("Loading iframe took too long")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_cms_subpages)

try:
   main_menu1 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='npsLogic_nodeViewEntry_c_/main_menu1_npsLogic']/img[@alt='-']")))
   print("main_menu1 open! Close it first")
   main_menu1.click()
   print("closed!")
except TimeoutException:
   print("main_menu1 was either already closed or something went wrong.")

driver.switch_to.parent_frame()

try:
    iframe_cms_subpages = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/iframe')))
    print("iframe found!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time or the window was open.")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_cms_subpages)

try:
   main_menu2 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='npsLogic_nodeViewEntry_e_/main_menu2_npsLogic']/img[@alt='+']")))
   print("main_menu2 closed! Needs to be opened first")
   main_menu2.click()
   print("main_menu2 opened!")
except TimeoutException:
   print("main_menu2 was either already open or something went wrong."
```